# Cross Frame Scripting in iframes

Tags: javascript, java, dom-events, jspx

I have a jsp page. It has 3 i-frames in it. I got a issue of cross frame scripting with it. I could load a page from any other domain to one of my i-frame. Can you please tell how to overcome this issue?
I have tried  following code:

```
             <style>
                html{display : none ; }
            </style>
            <script>
                if( self == top ) {
                    document.documentElement.style.display = 'block' ;
                } else {
                    top.location = self.location ;
                }


            </script>
```

and also I tried a filter which adds Header "X-FRAME-OPTIONS", SAMEORIGIN

Both are not working.

Answer (score 0):

For html page from different origin loaded into your iframe, you can't access that page's window or any other object.

For communicating between html page loaded into iframe from different origin , you have to use "postMessage" function. For details & examples google postMessage in javascript,you get plenty of tutorials of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, it won't allow your pages to be used in iframes from other domains.

```
function bust() {
    var urlRefer = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location;
    var envName = window.location.hostname;
    var envNameNew = new RegExp(envName);
    if (!(envNameNew.test(urlRefer))) {
        window.top.location="http://"+envName;  
    }
}
bust();
```